# Excel filter Multiple Value in One Cell

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am looking for help on filtering multiple values in one cell delimited by a comma. 
For example I have a spreadsheet with the following data:

```
Column A (Risk)     Column B (Risk Mitigation)

Risk A               Requirement1, Requirement2

Risk B               Requirement2, Requirement6, Requirement7

Risk C               Requirement1, Requirement3, Requirement9
```

When I filter on the 'Requirement Mitigation' Column I would like to see check boxes for the following:

```
Requirement1

Requirement2


Requirement3

Requirement4

Requirement5

...

Requirement9
```

So for my example when I only check the Requirement 1 filter box, only 'Risk A' and 'Risk C' rows would be displayed

Currently when I filter it does by the unique cell value, which gives me

```
Requirement1, Requirement2

Requirement2, Requirement6, Requirement7

Requirement1, Requirement3, Requirement9
```

Please note that above is just an example and I have thousand of individual requirements, so it would not be as simple as having one column per requirement.

I open to any suggestions including creating vbscripts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be tricky.

1. First you'll need to create a form that will contain a list box and populate that list box with the Requirements you have in their correct syntax.
2. Then you'll need to create a loop that will go through every cell in a column and save each of them to a string, you could make a one dimensional string array to save them all in that as well.
3. Then you'll need a loop that will go through each string and use the split function to seperate the strings with a delimeter, you'll need to set your delimiter to ", " to ensure it seperates the strings at the commas.
4. Then you'll need a loop that will run after you've made your selection from the listbox in your form. this loop will go through every string in your 2D array and check if it contains any of the requirements in your listbox. If it is not, run the code: Range("B" & x).EntireRow.Hidden = True where x is the row, you can use one of the variables in your loop for this.

---

If you need more specific information that this I may need to see what you've already done, it is possible as well to use this method to automatically populate the list box in your form.